# Problems with form validations

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

```
    <div id="form">
    <form method="post" action="register1.aspx" onsubmit="return validateForm();"name="register1"      >

    <h1>
        Register to exess the site</h1>

    <input type="text" name="firstname" class=" br"/>
    <em>First name</em><br />
    <span id="firstnmsg"></span><br />
    <input type="text" name="lastname" class=" br" /><em>Last name</em><br />
    <span id="lastnmsg"></span><br />
    <input type="text" name="username" class=" br" /><em>username</em><br>
    <span id="usermsg"></span><br />
    <input type="password" name="password" class=" br" /><em>password</em><br />
    <input type="password"name="password1" class=" br" /><em>Confirm password</em>
    <span id="pass1msg"></span><br />
    <input type="text" name="email" class=" br"/><em>Email!</em><br />
    <span id="emailmsg"></span><br />
    <select name="sex">
        <option>Please select a Gender</option>
        <option>Male</option>
        <option>Female</option>
        <em>Gender</em>
    </select><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register " onclick="return validateForm();"  />
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"  onclick="return resetMsg();"/>
    </form>
   <span> <%=Session["regstatus"] %></span>
</div>


     <div id="log_in">
     <h1><em>log in</em></h1>
     <form action="WebForm2.aspx"method="post" name="log_in" onsubmit="return     validateloginform"><br />
      <span id="usernamemsg"><%=Session["usernamemsg"] %> </span><input type="text" name="username_1" class="br" /><em>Username</em><br />
       <span id="passwordmsg"><%=Session ["passwordmsg"] %></span><input type="password" name="password_1" class="br" /><em>Password</em><br />
     <input type="submit" name="submit2"  onclick=" validateloginform"/>
     </form>
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">

     function isEmpty(str) {

return (str.length == 0);
}
function isNumeric(str) {

var c = true;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    c = !(isNaN(str[i]));
}
return c;
}
function isValid(str) {

var badChar = "\\;:!@#$%^&*()-_=+`~<>?[]{}|/,.";
for (var l = 0; l < str.length; l++) {
    for (var c = 0; c < badChar.length; c++) {
        if (str[l] == badChar[c]) {
            return true;
        }
        if (str[l] == " " || str[l] == "\"" || str[l] == "\'") {
            return true;
        }
    }
    }
 return false;
 }
 function isShort(str) {
  return (str.length < 3);
}
    //Reset Error Messages Function -->
function resetMsg() {

document.getElementById("firstnmsg").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("lastnmsg").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("usermsg").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("passwordmsg").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("pssword1msg").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("emailmsg").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("BdateMsg").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("UnameMsg").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("PwdMsg").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("LoginError").innerHTML = "";
return true;
}
 //Main Sign Up Form Validation Function -->
function validateForm() {
resetMsg();
var val = true;
//First Name Validation ---------------------------------------->
if (isEmpty(register1.firstname.value)) {
    document.getElementById("firstnmsg").innerHTML = " Empty";
    val = false;
}
else {
    if (isNumeric(register1.firstname.value) || isValid(signup.firstname.value)) {
        document.getElementById("firstnmsg").innerHTML = " Letters Only";
        val = false;
    }
    else {
        if (isShort(register1.firstname.value)) {
            document.getElementById("firstnmsg").innerHTML = " Too Short";
            val = false;
        }
    }
}
//Last Name Validation ------------------>
if (isEmpty(register1.lastname.value)) {
    document.getElementById("lastnmsg").innerHTML = " Empty";
    val = false;
}
else {
    if (isNumeric(register1.lastname.value) || isValid(signup.lastname.value)) {
        document.getElementById("lastnmsg").innerHTML = " Letters Only";
        val = false;
    }
    else {
        if (isShort(register1.lastname.value)) {
            document.getElementById("lastnmsg").innerHTML = " Too Short";
            val = false;
        }
    }
}
//Username Validation --------------------------------------------->
if (isEmpty(register1.username.value)) {
    document.getElementById("usermsg").innerHTML = " Empty";
    val = false;
}
else {
    if (!isNumeric(register1.username.value)) {
        document.getElementById("usermsg").innerHTML = " Use Numbers";
    }
    else {
        if (isShort(register1.username.value)) {
            document.getElementById("usermsg").innerHTML = " Too Short";
            val = false;
        }
    }
}
//Password Validation ----------------------------------------------->
if (isEmpty(register1.password1.value)) {
    document.getElementById("Password1Msg").innerHTML = " Empty";
    val = false;
}
else {
    if (isValid(register1.password.value)) {
        document.getElementById("Password1Msg").innerHTML = " Invalid";
    }
    else {
        if (register1.password.value == register1.password1.value) {
            if (signup.password1.value.length < 6 && signup.password1.value != "") {
                document.getElementById("pass1msg").innerHTML = " Too Short";
                val = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("pass1msg").innerHTML = " Don't Match";
            val = false;
        }
    }
}
//Email Validation -------------------------------------->
var EmailField = document.forms["register1"]["email"].value;
var atpos = EmailField.indexOf("@");
var dotpos = EmailField.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= EmailField.length) {
    document.getElementById("emailmsg").innerHTML = " Invalid Email";
    val = false;
}
if (EmailField == null || EmailField == "") {
    document.getElementById("emailmsg").innerHTML = " Empty";
    val = false;
}

  //Main Login Validation Function -->
function validateLoginForm() {
resetMsg();
var val = true;
//Username Validation
if (isEmpty(log_in.username.value)) {
    document.getElementById("usernamemsg").innerHTML = " Empty";
    val = false;
}
//Password Validation
if (isEmpty(log_in.password.value)) {
    document.getElementById("passwordmsg").innerHTML = " Empty";
    val = false;
}
return val;
}
     </script>
```

The validations won't work and I dont know why. This is a school project.
my main problem is that the script isnt running when im submiting the form ,when there even some errors at the form(what the user submits) it still goes to the next page and no innerHtml massage is shown.

Comment: Tell us what's going on. Why is it not working? Are there any errors? No one wants to read through all your code to find out what's happening.

Comment: of course,my main problem is that when there are errors in the form it just goes to the next page,i tried to show the errors as an innerHtml .i think that the problem is that validations cant get to the objects in the form and that the javascript validation arent running at all when i am submiting the form although that i have added "onSubmit=return validateForm();"

Answer (score 0):

Here, I went through your code, refractored a lot of it, wrote out some comments on how to improve it.

What stops the form from submitting is returning false. You're returning a variable called val, and if there is an error that variable is set to false, thus returning false and preventing the form from submitting.

I recommend taking the JS and putting it in your text editor and reading through everything. You should learn a good bit.

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/2x5LU/

I just did first name cause I have to work now, but you should be able to work off of this.

```
function validateForm(){
    resetMsg();
    var val = true;

    if(isEmpty(firstName.value)){
        firstNameMsg = 'Empty';
        val = false;
    }else if(isNumeric(firstName.value)){
        firstNameMsg = 'Letters Only';
        val = false;
    }else if(isShort(firstName.value)){
        firstNameMsg = 'Too Short';
        val = false;
    }

    return val;
}
```

Comment: first of all wanted to say thanks ,but you understanded that my problem is that the validations arent recognizing any errors right? and could you please send me as a comment what you sent me in the link?